# Automation script to download and extract decompressed files using bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash, loops, wget, tar

I created a script here and the script is all about checking the disk space if the disk space had enough space then it will download the file needed after that it will extract the file 5 times and it must not extract the last `tar.gz` file . But when I executed the script I got a problem here. For the extract side it will just extract 1 time but I already out it 5 times.

```
#!/bin/bash

outout=$(df -h)
file=$(awk -F = '{print $2}' config.txt)
filename=$(echo "$bundle" | awk -F / '{print $11}')
diskspace=$(df -h /var/ | sed '1d' | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d'%' -f1)
allowed=10

address=$(awk -F = '{print $2}' newconfig.txt)

if [ "${diskspace}" -gt "${allowed}" ]; then

#       cd "/var/"
        wget $bundle
else
        echo "Not enough space to download the bundle"
        echo $output
    exit
fi


 i=0
for tarfile in *.tar.gz
                        do
                         $(($i++))
                         [ $i = 5 ] && break
                tar -xf "$tarfile"
 done
```

For the `config.txt`
 `https://www.google.com.ph/files.tar.gz`

files.tar.gz is composed of 5 tar inside

files1.tar.gz -> files2.tar.gz - > files3.tar.gz -> files4.tar.gz - > files5.tar.gz

What should I do to extract it five times until files5.tar.gz will display and it must not be extracted.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should use `while` loop instead of `for tarfile in *.tar.gz` since files1.tar.gz ... files5.tar.gz does not exist when for loop started.

Comment: how to do it, can you please give me code for it ?

Comment: `for tarfile in *.tar.gz; do $(($i++)) [ $i = 5 ] && break tar -xf "$tarfile"
 done ` -- how to convert it to while loop?

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't figure out the exact code you wan't,
I would give a example code how to use `while` loop instead

```
i=0
tar xf files.tar.gz
while [ $i -lt 4 ];do
 ((i++))
 tar xf files${i}.tar.gz
done
```

Or use `for` to do the same thing.

```
for i in "" {1..4};do
  tar xf files${i}.tar.gz
done
```

These code executes following command

```
tar xf files.tar.gz
tar xf files1.tar.gz
tar xf files2.tar.gz
tar xf files3.tar.gz
tar xf files4.tar.gz
```

Comment: I really don't get the answer for this question